# In HTML5, different browsers support different formats of video

Tags: video, html5

Does it mean that I need videos of multiple formats so that it can be played on different browsers by adding multiple sources to the  tag?

Answer (score 2):

> Minimally, MP4 + either WebM or Ogg, or maybe both.

--[How many formats do I need for HTML5 video?](http://blog.zencoder.com/2010/10/06/how-many-formats-do-i-need-for-html5-video/)

As far as I'm aware, the situation hasn't changed significantly. And from what I've seen in some debates with representatives of the various browsers, it's not going to be resolved for a while.